# how to distinguish norwegian characters

Tags: java, character, ascii

Norwegian alphabet have characters such as Ø, Å, Æ..

```
    char character = 'Ø';
    int ascii = (int) character;
    System.out.println(ascii);
```

And it returns = 65533

```
    char character = 'Æ';
    int ascii = (int) character;
    System.out.println(ascii);
```

And it also returns = 65533

How does it possible to distinguish these characters when they are entered from keyboard?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Do you want to work exclusively at character level? You should be able to achieve this through regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach to your problem could be to use the [`.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method available in the string class. This would allow you to replace all instances which match the given regular expression. Thus, the code below:

```
    String input = "Løre lære i kjøpe";
    String result = input.replaceAll("ø", "oo");
    result = result.replaceAll("æ", "ae");
    System.out.println(result);
```

Would yield:

```
Loore laere i kjoope
```

Thus, you could have a method which processes the text through a series of replace calls. You could add some intelligence to it and allow it to also replace capitalized words with their English equivalent.

If you have a lot of them, you could create a configuration file which your application then loads in a `Map` like structure. You could then iterate over the map and use it to replace chunks of text from your source string.

Comment: @vlcod: What input string are you using?

Comment: @vlcod: Are typing the letters yourself or are you parsing strings? Some IDE's have limited capabilities within their consoles.

Comment: You are not using any regex functionality here, so `replace()` is better than `replaceAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are wrong. The characters are actually 216 and 198. `65533` is the [Unicode Replacement Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) which is used when an unsupported character is encountered (usually due to wrong encoding). If it works in Eclipse, then check your IDEA settings for any encoding options.

Recommended reading: http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html